# TF aws_security_group: Inappropriate value for attribute "ingress": attributes "prefix_list_ids", "security_groups", and "self" are required

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I'm learning Terraform and AWS and I'm having trouble by creating an `aws_security_group` resource.

I copied from the [Terraform Docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group) an example of this resource, then I configured with my data (I want to access my EC2 resources via SSH. I know that is not a good practice but I'm only learning and I'm going to destroy after the test)

```
resource "aws_security_group" "allow_tls_ssh" {
  name        = "allow_tls"
  description = "Allow TLS inbound traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  ingress = [
    {
      description      = "TLS from VPC"
      from_port        = 443
      to_port          = 443
      protocol         = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks      = [aws_vpc.vpc.cidr_block]
      ipv6_cidr_blocks = [aws_vpc.vpc.ipv6_cidr_block]
      prefix_list_ids  = []
      security_groups  = []
      self = false
    },
    {
      description      = "SSH from VPC"
      from_port        = 22
      to_port          = 22
      protocol         = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks      = [aws_vpc.vpc.cidr_block]
      ipv6_cidr_blocks = [aws_vpc.vpc.ipv6_cidr_block]
      prefix_list_ids  = []
      security_groups  = []
      self = false
    },
    {
      description      = "HTTP from VPC"
      from_port        = 80
      to_port          = 80
      protocol         = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks      = [aws_vpc.vpc.cidr_block]
      ipv6_cidr_blocks = [aws_vpc.vpc.ipv6_cidr_block]
      prefix_list_ids  = []
      security_groups  = []
      self = false
    }
  ]

  tags = {
    Name = "allow_tls_ssh"
  }
}
```

Then, when I `terraform apply` I get:

```
(...)

│   59:     }
│   60:   ]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_vpc.vpc.cidr_block will be known only after apply
│     │ aws_vpc.vpc.ipv6_cidr_block will be known only after apply
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "ingress": element 0: attributes "prefix_list_ids", "security_groups", and "self" are required.
╵
```

This error confuses me. Why do I have to indicate security_groups when I'm creating one?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/69080432/2291321 answer your question? Basically it comes down to you using [attribute as block style](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/attr-as-blocks.html).

Answer (score 0):

The error corresponds to the attribute `security_groups` inside the ingress rules you are defining. A rule in a security group could be based on CIDR block, security groups or prefixed list. Since you want to use CIDR blocks just give null value to the others:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "allow_tls_ssh" {
  name        = "allow_tls"
  description = "Allow TLS inbound traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  ingress = [
    {
      description      = "TLS from VPC"
      from_port        = 443
      to_port          = 443
      protocol         = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks      = [aws_vpc.vpc.cidr_block]
      ipv6_cidr_blocks = [aws_vpc.vpc.ipv6_cidr_block]
      prefix_list_ids  = null
      security_groups  = null
      self = false
    },
    {
      description      = "SSH from VPC"
      from_port        = 22
      to_port          = 22
      protocol         = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks      = [aws_vpc.vpc.cidr_block]
      ipv6_cidr_blocks = [aws_vpc.vpc.ipv6_cidr_block]
      prefix_list_ids  = null
      security_groups  = null
      self = false
    },
    {
      description      = "HTTP from VPC"
      from_port        = 80
      to_port          = 80
      protocol         = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks      = [aws_vpc.vpc.cidr_block]
      ipv6_cidr_blocks = [aws_vpc.vpc.ipv6_cidr_block]
      prefix_list_ids  = null
      security_groups  = null
      self = false
    }
  ]

  tags = {
    Name = "allow_tls_ssh"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the two attributes from ingress rules:

```
prefix_list_ids  = []
security_groups  = []
```

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

Your problem is that `ingress` and `egress` are both processed in [attribute-as-blocks mode](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/attr-as-blocks.html). See for example the [first line](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group#ingress) of the `ingress` argument documentation.

You can read the linked documentation for what `attribute-as-blocks mode` for more details. Specifically, see the quote in [this section](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/attr-as-blocks.html) (emphasis mine):

> Because of the rule that argument declarations like this fully override any default value, when creating a list-of-objects expression directly the usual handling of optional arguments does not apply, **so all of the arguments must be assigned a value, even if it's an explicit null**

So, since you are using "argument syntax" (`ingress = [...]`) instead of the recommended blocks syntax, you need to **explicitly** define these "optional" values as null.

### Why are you getting the 'Inappropriate value' errors?

You are explicitly providing them now, after your edit, so why still the same erorr?

An Ingress/egress rule can only be based on ONE of [(cidr and/or ipv6 cidr), security_groups, prefix_list_ids], so providing more than one of those will conflict and cause this error. This is slightly unclear in the security group resource documentation.

To confirm, you can see the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group_rule#argument-reference) for the resource `aws_security_group_rule`, which says more explicity that, for example:

> `cidr_blocks` - (Optional) List of CIDR blocks. Cannot be specified with `source_security_group_id` or `self`.
> `self` - (Optional) Whether the security group itself will be added as a source to this ingress rule. Cannot be specified with `cidr_blocks`, `ipv6_cidr_blocks`, or `source_security_group_id`.

So this explains why `self` is also in the list of args with `inappropriate value`s. Notice `cidr_blocks` and `ipv6_cidr_blocks` do not have any conflict issues listed there, so you are fine listing both.

So, setting the args you don't need as `null` should fix your issue.

### Using Blocks Instead

The better option is to switch to the block syntax and omit needing to set the unnecessary optional values, which is basically the same as explicitly setting them to `null` anyway:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "allow_tls_ssh" {
  name        = "allow_tls"
  description = "Allow TLS inbound traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  ingress {
      description      = "TLS from VPC"
      from_port        = 443
      to_port          = 443
      protocol         = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks      = [aws_vpc.vpc.cidr_block]
      ipv6_cidr_blocks = [aws_vpc.vpc.ipv6_cidr_block]
    }
    ingress {
      description      = "SSH from VPC"
      from_port        = 22
      to_port          = 22
      protocol         = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks      = [aws_vpc.vpc.cidr_block]
      ipv6_cidr_blocks = [aws_vpc.vpc.ipv6_cidr_block]
    }
    ingress {
      description      = "HTTP from VPC"
      from_port        = 80
      to_port          = 80
      protocol         = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks      = [aws_vpc.vpc.cidr_block]
      ipv6_cidr_blocks = [aws_vpc.vpc.ipv6_cidr_block]
    }
  ]
```

This way, your solution is shorter too as the optional args are now finally optional again!

Answer (score -1):

I'm also getting same issue when trying to create a security group to open all traffic but, I have found solution by trying this "null" for the below. I have used it for all traffic,if you want to specify certain traffic feel free to modify it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).