# Referencing map objects in TF

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

I need feedback.  I have the below partial tf code.    I am getting "**Error: Incorrect attribute value type... Inappropriate value for attribute "security_rule": set of object required.**".  Looks like the reference to the map value is not set correctly but can't seem to figure it out.  What am I missing? Thanks

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
input.tfvars
-----------------

test_nsg = {
  "testnsg_1" = {
    location = "West US"
    rules = {
      "AllOutbound" = {
        priority                   = 300
        direction                  = "Outbound"
        access                     = "Allow"
        protocol                   = "Tcp"
        source_port_range          = "*"
        destination_port_range     = "*"
        source_address_prefix      = "*"
        destination_address_prefix = "*"
      },
      "AllowSSH" = {
        priority                   = 400
        direction                  = "Inbound"
        access                     = "Allow"
        protocol                   = "Tcp"
        source_port_range          = "*"
        destination_port_range     = "22"
        source_address_prefix      = "*"
        destination_address_prefix = "*"
      },
    }
  },
  "testnsg_2" = {
    rules = {}
  },
  "testnsg_3" = {
    rules = {
      "AllOutbound" = {
        priority                   = 500
        direction                  = "Outbound"
        access                     = "Allow"
        protocol                   = "Tcp"
        source_port_range          = "*"
        destination_port_range     = "*"
        source_address_prefix      = "*"
        destination_address_prefix = "*"
      },
    }
  },
}


nsg.tf
-------

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg" {
  for_each = var.test_nsg

  name                = each.key
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name
  tags                = var.tags
  security_rule       = each.value.rules
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be [List of objects](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/network_security_group#security_rule), and in your case it is a map of objects. I think the following should work:

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg" {
  for_each = var.test_nsg

  name                = each.key
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name
  tags                = var.tags
  security_rule       = values(each.value.rules)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I am getting "Error: Call to unknown function... │ Inappropriate value for attribute "security_rule": element 0: attributes
│ "description", "destination_address_prefixes",
│ "destination_application_security_group_ids", "destination_port_ranges",
│ "name", "source_address_prefixes", "source_application_security_group_ids",
│ and "source_port_ranges" are required."

Comment: @UltraGC You have to provide all possible arguments (name, destination_application_security_group_ids, ...) with some default values in your test_nsg. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69080432/248823) for example. The example is for AWS, but the same applies to azure.